# How to decide if a league table is admissible?

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

Let's consider a league of *n* teams where each team plays against all the others exactly two times with three possible results: win, loss or draw. A win is worth 2 points, a draw 1, a loss 0. We want to decide if a league table is admissible.

I'm trying to implement a polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem. I thought about using network flow techniques (as in chapter 7 of "Algorithm Design" by Kleinberg & Tardos) but couldn't come up with anything concrete.

An ideal solution would look like this

```
    IsAdmissible
    Input: Final league table
    {
         ...
    }
    Output: TRUE if there's a combination of matches resulting in given table
            FALSE otherwise
```

Comment: What is an admissible league ?

Comment: An admissible league table is one for which there is a combination of results for it. For example, if we have 20 teams the greatest amount of points for a team is 114, so a league table with a team having 115 points is not admissible.

Comment: Please edit problem specifications into the question, not as comments.  Include all specifications.  Are there any other table columns to consider?

Comment: Why 114? Is a win worth 2 points or 3 points?

Answer (score 1):

Fast preliminary check: the sum of the scores of all teams must satisfy:

- 20*19*2 ≤ sum(s) ≤ 20*19*3

Each team plays 38 games, and in each game, it can score 0, 1 or 3 points. 
The total points for each team, s, must satisfy:

- d + 3*w = s, where d and w are non-negative integers (d - number of draws, w - number of wins)
- d + w ≤ 38

It is easy to find all valid (d, w) for each team.

The table is admissible if there is a valid (d, w) for each team, such that:

- for any 2 teams, sum(w) ≤ 38+36
  for any 3 teams, sum(w) ≤ 38+36+34
  for any n teams, sum(w) ≤ 38+36+...+(40-2n)

  (sort the teams by decreasing score; it is sufficient to perform a single check for each n)
- sum(d) = 4560 - 2*sum(s)
- sum(w) = sum(s) - 1520

The two equations above follow from the following facts:

- sum(s) = sum(d) + 3*sum(w)    (draw = 1 point, win = 3 points)
- sum(d)/2 + sum(w) = 20*19*2    (each game ends with a win or with two draws)

All these conditions are necessary. I believe (but haven't proved) they are sufficient.